# Are acronyms pronounced as a one word or separately?

Tags: pronunciation, acronyms

In English language there are innumerable **Acronyms**, but what I don’t know is that when do we pronounce an acronym as one word and when as separate Letters?

- For Instance, **UNICEF** is pronounced /ˈjuːnɪsef/, which sounds as a one word. On the other hand, **IOM** is pronounced /ʌɪəʊˈɛm / as though it was three words.

Are there any rules for Acronyms pronunciation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my experience, it is usually from usage, but seems to follow an informal rule that if it looks like a pronounceable word it is often used that way and usually more than 3 letters.

Examples of being used as a ***word*** are

> NATO - North Atlantic Treaty Organization
>   FIFA - Fédération Internationale de Football Association
>   NAFTA - North American Free Trade Agreement

Examples of not

> iOS - Apple's Operating System
>   AWS - Amazon Web Services
>   IOU - short for "**I owe you**"
>   IOC - International Olympic Committee

An exception is

> IBM - International Business Machine

which does get pronounced as a ***word*** by people familiar with the company, usually in the context of **I**'ve **B**een **M**oved, referring to the extensive relocations which occur.

Comment: And, unfortunately, there are those that are both, like SQL, which for some is **Ess Queue Ell** and some is **Sequel**.  Also, the military have [a massive number of acronyms](https://www.militaryfactory.com/glossary.asp), most (but not all) of which are pronounced as separate letters, and which a recruit is expected to learn on the job.

Comment: People familiar with IBM actually pronounce it "ibbem"?  That's a new one to me.